# Attribute Error: 'Embedding' object has no attribute 'embeddings' - TensorFlow & Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Okay so I have a keras model that I fully ran and then saved the weights with this line:

```
model.save_weights("rho_beta_true_tf", save_format="tf")
```

Then in another file I build just the model and then I load the weights from the model I ran above using this line:

```
model_build.load_weights("rho_beta_true_tf")
```

When I then go to call some of the attributes everything displays correctly except when I try to run this line:

```
model_build.stimuli.embeddings
```

or

```
model_build.stimuli.embeddings.numpy()[0]
```

I get an attribute error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'Embedding' object has no attribute 'embeddings'
```

This line is supposed to return a tensor and if I call any other attributes so far it works so I am not sure if it just can't find the tensors or if the problem is something else. Could someone please help me figure out how to solve this attribute Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that because I had saved the weights in tf format I had to follow this step in the tensor flow documentation:

> For user-defined classes which inherit from tf.keras.Model, Layer instances must be assigned to object attributes, typically in the constructor.

So then the line

```
build_model.stimuli.embedding(put the directory path to your custom embedding layer here)
```

worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.get_weights()`:

```
model_build.stimuli.get_weights()
```

Comment: Okay, so when I do that line I get an empty list. It just shows up as " [ ] ". Do you have any other suggestions on how I can get it to not be empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Definition of a basic neural network class
class SimpleBrokenModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config=MASTER_CONFIG):
        super(SimpleBrokenModel, self).__init__()  # Inherit from nn.Module
        # Rest of the code ...

    # Forward pass function for the base model
    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        # Embedding layer converts character indices to vectors
        x = self.embedding(idx)

        # Linear layers for modeling relationships between features
        a = self.linear(x)

        # Apply softmax activation to obtain probability distribution
        logits = F.softmax(a, dim=-1)

        # If targets are provided, calculate and return the cross-entropy loss
        if targets is not None:
            # Reshape logits and targets for cross-entropy calculation
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, self.config['vocab_size']), targets.view(-1))
            return logits, loss
        # If targets are not provided, return the logits
        else:
            return logits

# Update MASTER_CONFIG with the dimension of linear layers (128)
MASTER_CONFIG.update({
    'd_model': 128,
})

# Instantiate the SimpleBrokenModel using the updated MASTER_CONFIG
model = SimpleBrokenModel(MASTER_CONFIG)

# Print the total number of parameters in the model
print("Total number of parameters in the Simple Neural Network Model:", sum([m.numel() for m in model.parameters()]))
for the above code im getting error please help me...

# Obtain batches for training using the specified batch size and context window
xs, ys = get_batches(dataset, 'train', MASTER_CONFIG['batch_size'], MASTER_CONFIG['context_window'])

# Calculate logits and loss using the model
logits, loss = model(xs, ys)`enter code here`
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35726774)